# Combine keys and values of a HashMap to a Set

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, There can be duplicate values for the unique keys. Is there a way to convert the HashMap to a `Set<Integer>` which contains unique Integers of both the keys and values.

This can definitely be done in two loops by iterating over the keySet() and .values(). I'm would like to know whether this is possible in java 8 streams.

Comment: please explore `Collections` Class. A utility class which contains all kind of method to convert sort and many more things

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Dude I know that this is solvable. I'm looking to see if there is a way to do is in java8 stream.

Comment: "There can be duplicate values for the unique keys." that statement makes no sense.  If something is unique it does not have duplicates.  Keys are unique by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the stream function to combine both the values and the keys:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = ...
Set<Integer> total = Stream.concat(
     map.keySet().stream(), 
     map.values().stream()
).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This uses the map's `keySet().stream()` and `values().stream()` to get a stream of both, then connects them using [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-), then finally turns it into a set. The call to `.toSet()` prevents duplicate elements, because a set cannot contain duplicate elements.

This trick can also be used if the keys are double, and the values are floats, in this case java will give the greatest common divider class back, what in this case is Number.

Comment: Awesome. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I prefer [JB Nizet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35646442/464306). It's cleaner, more DRY, only iterates over the map once.

Comment: When the keys are double, and the values are floats, identical numbers get considered non-equal because of the different object type. I doubt that there is a use case where this is desired.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `addAll()` twice is simple as hell and very readable, so that should be your solution. But if you want your curiosity to be satisfied, you can use this stream based solution (less readable, probably less efficient):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = ...;
Set<Integer> result = map.entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just get all keys as a set and then add all values with `addAll`

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = ...
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());
set.addAll(map.values());
```

If you really really want to use Java 8 streams you can do the following but I don't see how this would be any better:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = ...
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
map.keySet().stream().forEach(n -> set.add(n));
map.values().stream().forEach(n -> set.add(n));
```

Or look at all the other solutions but in my opinion a simple `addAll` works best here. It should be the most efficient and definetelly the most readable way to do it.

Comment: The OP asks whether it is possible to do this with Java8 streams

Comment: @ScaryWombat but he also thinks the only alternative is to iterate through the keys and values. A two-line solution using addAll() is better, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate once over entry set, which will give you all pairs. Whether you do it through streams api or not is irrelevant, because the complexity of this operation remains the same.

```
public class StreamMapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(1, 20);
        map.put(2, 20);
        map.put(3, 10);
        map.put(4, 30);
        map.put(5, 20);
        map.put(6, 10);

        Set<Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```